# Where does my Huffman encoding method go wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, huffman-code

I am trying to code a Huffman string encoding algorithm.

My solution works this way:

1. since every letter in the string have a special binary code associated to it, search the binary tree and when a letter is found, add it to the map with binary code. (**where I went wrong is here**)
2. iterate on the string, and for each letter, associate the value associated with the key of the letter of the map.

I don't have the tree printed somewhere, even tough it could help you help me, but here is what I get for the string **abracadabra**, and what I should get:

Correct Code : `000010000110110101111101011000111110110100111011101100101101110000110000110111100101111101010010`

What I get :
`00001000111011010110101111010101100011101011010`

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

string codes = "";

void getMapCharBinaryCode(Node root, string &prefix, map <char, string> &m){
    if(!root) return;
    if(root->value){
        if(!m.count(root->value)){
            m[root->value] = prefix;
            prefix = "";
        } 
    }
    if(root->leftChild){
        getMapCharBinaryCode(root->leftChild, prefix += "0",m);
    }
    if(root->rightChild){
        getMapCharBinaryCode(root->rightChild, prefix += "1",m);
    }
   
}

string encode(string text, Node tree){
    // text is "abracadabra"
    // create map for each char -> binary code
    map<char, string> m;
    string prefix = "";
    getMapCharBinaryCode(tree, prefix, m);
    
    // iterate on text and assign each letter with binary code from map
    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        codes += m[text[i]];
    }
    return codes;
}
```

Comment: First of all try to minimize the input needed to create the faulty output. Then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values, to see when and where things go wrong.

Comment: What is the input ```text```?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including suitable input, to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `getMapCharBinaryCode(root->leftChild, prefix += "0",m);` -- I could look at this 10 times, and not give an answer of what that line will result in, especially what the second parameter will give the calling function.

Comment: `getMapCharBinaryCode(root->rightChild, prefix += "1",m);` -- I will take a guess and state that this line leads to unspecified behavior.  Parameters in C++ can be processed in any order, not strictly left-to-right.  Then you have that `+=` going on in the second parameter -- is that executed after or before the function is called?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The C and C++ result of `+=` in an expression is well defined, and must be executed before the call. What is passed is the value after doing the `+=`. The only ambiguity would be if the first or third argument also depended on `prefix`, in which the ordering of execution of the arguments would affect that. But they do not depend on `prefix`.

Comment: Hi Yolan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I am glad the answer given by Mark worked for you (it's a good answer). However, it's not really our 'style' to add your corrected code to your question - this *could* be seen as somehow 'spoiling' the continuity. It is sufficient that you have marked the answer as "Accepted" - that way, others who view this Q/A will know that it worked as expected.

Comment: Though Yolan can, if they want, post an _answer_ to their own question with the corrected code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are destroying the code in `prefix` when you save a leaf with `prefix = ""`, where the code is needed when dropping back down the tree and going to the next branch.

You can maintain a single storage area for `prefix` as you have, passing it by reference. However you need to manage the length of `prefix` as you go up and down the tree, and you need to not add a `0`, and then add a `1` to *that* for the two branches, adding `01` for the right branch instead of `1`.

As a starting point, you should just pass `prefix` by value, which makes copies, but does not require care in management. Get rid of the `&` and replace the `prefix +=` with `prefix +`. Get rid of the `prefix = ""`, which then does nothing.

Comment: @YolanMaldonado please do *not* edit the question to include the answer

Comment: That's a very nice suggestion :) I don't think the OP got notified of your comment though. Would it be too much trouble to copy this comment into a comment on the OP's  question? I think they'd benefit from it a lot, and they may end up putting up a really answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @yolanmaldonado Now that you got that working, you can run a single referenced `prefix` up and down, which is more efficient. You need to add one character for the left branch, then _replace_ that character (not add another) for the right branch, and then _delete_ that character before returning, to restore `prefix` to its state when the routine was entered. Do not mess with `prefix` when processing a leaf.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks for editing the comment to include a ping for the OP, I appreciate it :)